# iAd error how to resolve it?

Tags: iphone, iad

i add iAd into UIVIew at buttom of TableView, it also error when fast scroll up/down.

Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    if(NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView") != nil) {
        ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
        adView.delegate = self;
        adView.hidden = YES;
        [self.iAdBanner addSubview:adView];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // assumes the banner view is at the top of the screen.
        adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -150);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        //[adView release];
    }
    else {
        //NSLog(@"iad not available");
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    //NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");
    //[self moveBannerViewOnscreen];
    if (banner.hidden)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // assumes the banner view is offset 50 pixels so that it is not visible.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 150);
        banner.hidden = NO;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        //self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //NSLog(@"bannerView error");
    //[self moveBannerViewOffscreen];
    //* 
    if (!banner.hidden)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // assumes the banner view is at the top of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -150);
        [UIView commitAnimations];//*/
        banner.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    //NSLog(@"bannerViewActionShouldBegin");
    //[super bannerViewActionShouldBegin:banner willLeaveApplication:willLeave];
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    //NSLog(@"bannerViewActionDidFinish");
}
```

Error Log

```
2010-07-27 11:58:58.547 PantipCafe[730:307] ******* Accessibility Status Changed: On
2010-07-27 11:58:59.068 PantipCafe[730:307] ********** Loading AX for: com.ragopor.pantip ************
2010-07-27 11:59:01.345 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 11:59:05.182 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 11:59:11.653 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 11:59:13.224 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 11:59:25.437 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 11:59:28.434 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 12:00:06.220 PantipCafe[730:307] CPDistributedMessagingCenter attempting to send reply to a dead port. Reply keys: (null)
2010-07-27 12:00:10.241 PantipCafe[730:307] -[__NSCFType bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x544e9b0
2010-07-27 12:00:10.265 PantipCafe[730:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x544e9b0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x3303ffd3 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x309e7871 objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x33043a77 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x33042f15 ___forwarding___ + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x32fd5680 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   iAd                                 0x31bdc25d -[ADBannerView _sanitizeAndForwardErrorToDelegate:] + 48
    6   iAd                                 0x31bdafcf -[ADBannerView sessionBannerViewDidFailToReceiveAd:withError:] + 38
    7   iAd                                 0x31be8ca9 -[ADSession bannerViewDidFailToReceiveAddWithErrorMessage:userInfo:auditToken:] + 116
    8   AppSupport                          0x32a4d0b5 -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _dispatchMessageNamed:userInfo:reply:auditToken:] + 172
    9   AppSupport                          0x32a4df87 processMessage + 514
    10  AppSupport                          0x32a4e1cb _CPDMMessage + 74
    11  AppSupport                          0x32a4ede9 _XMessage + 248
    12  AppSupport                          0x32a412c3 migHelperRecievePortCallout + 138
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x33015aab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x3301784f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x3301862d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x32fc18eb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x32fc17f3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x302dd673 GSEventRunModal + 114
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x302dd71f GSEventRun + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x33720cff -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    21  UIKit                               0x3371f8c7 UIApplicationMain + 670
    22  PantipCafe                          0x00002ceb main + 42
    23  PantipCafe                          0x00002c88 start + 52
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

Comment: I've been looking at this issue and it is possible that it only occurs on certain versions of iOS. What versions of iOS is it happening for you?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to answer with your header file, but did you set the interface to implement the  delegate interface?  You need to do that in your UIViewController in order to capture the iAd messages.  And don't forget to #import .

If you set things up with Interface Builder -- and AFAICT you didn't and just create the iAd on the fly -- then there are other issues with setting your iAd delegate to your view which you do by connecting the iAd delegate to the "File's Owner" socket.

Anyway, check your header file and I hope this helps you both.