# ADBannerView crashes internally with _sanitizeAndForwardErrorToDelegate: > doesNotRecognizeSelector

Tags: iphone, crash, iad

AdBannerView crashes with `_sanitizeAndForwardErrorToDelegate` . is this some internal crash?

i went through 3 of these questions in stack overflow. none have answers . can someone give some hints if you guys faced this?

i am setting delegate to nil before releasing .

some previous crashes similar posted in stackoverflow issues:

[Strange iAd Errors with iOS 4.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924642/strange-iad-errors-with-ios-4-3-3)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598376/iphone-iad-error

[iAd error how to resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340922/iad-error-how-to-resolve-it)

none have helpful ansers. how to know what is causing crash here?

Comment: i tried autoreleaseing and setting delegate to nil, before removing from superview. seems to have fixed the issue for now.